# java Clip loop not working

Tags: java, loops, audio, javasound, clip

I have a simple Clip method, to play back small wav sounds. Yeah i found the method clip.loop() right now, but anyway i cannot understand why my method isnt working.

Heres the code:

```
public void playSound(final String sound, final boolean loop, final int repeatTime){
    try {
        sounds.get(sound).open();
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int repeatCount = 1;
            Clip actualClip = sounds.get(sound);
            actualClip.setFramePosition(0);
            actualClip.start();
            while(true){
                System.out.println("repeat c: " + repeatCount + ",   frames left: " + (actualClip.getFrameLength() - actualClip.getFramePosition()));
                if(actualClip.getFramePosition() >= actualClip.getFrameLength()){
                    actualClip.stop();
                    actualClip.setFramePosition(0);
                    actualClip.start();
                    repeatCount++;
                }
                if(!loop && repeatCount > repeatTime){
                    break;
                }
            }
            actualClip.stop();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

its String sound, becaus im getting it out of an hashmap. When i call it with

```
playSound(key, false, 10);
```

The sound repeats itself 10 times. But when i call it again, (i do it with an button), its playing just 4 - 8 times, so the loop isnt working right. What im making wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) A `Clip` does not require a separate `Thread`.

Comment: I guess it should be `if(!loop || repeatCount > repeatTime)`. BTW, why not use `for` instead of `while`? It would make your code much more readable.

Comment: Thank you... that is actualy a sscce o.O ok fail... really it should be and.

Answer (score 1):

- `if(!loop || repeatCount > repeatTime)` should be OR rather then AND.
- Use `for` loop instead of `while`.
- The problem is probably that you try `open`ning the same clip over and over. To do that, you must first get a new `AudioInputStream` to be `open`ed by this `Clip`.

Comment: Thank you it really should be or.  Its an while true loop - how  puld i use for here? And im just opening it when its finished.